# Any plugin for bluetooth mesh for React-native?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm new to react-native
I got one requirement, using react-native, we have to develop IOT app
Which will have

1. Bluetooth Mesh using Bluetooth Low Energy devices
2. Able to add and delete a device

can some one suggest me a plugin in react-native or javascript

Answer (score 1):

As a start-up, we tried to use 2 plugins for our ble tool.

We started with [Ble Manager](https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager) but we had some limitations / bugs we coulnd't easely fix.

Then we tried [Ble PLX](https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx) which is, in my opinion, harder to use and slower but we didn't had the same issues. Our app is now in production with Ble PLX, we still have bugs on our side but the plugin is doing the job.

Comment: Thanks Poptocrack